# I/O Redirection in C

Tags: c, file, io, io-redirection

I'm writing this code in order to redirect the standart input into a file

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE* log = fopen("log.txt", "a");
    char c = ' ';
    while (c != 'q') {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        printf("%c", c);
        fputs(&c, log);
    }

    fclose(log);

}
```

But when I type: "Hello worldq", I get this in the log file:

```
H˜|‚ue˜|‚ul˜|‚ul˜|‚uo˜|‚u ˜|‚uw˜|‚uo˜|‚ur˜|‚ul˜|‚ud˜|‚uq˜|‚u
```

What is this ~|,u and how do I fix it?

Comment: `fputs(&c, log);` --> `fputc(c, log);`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `fputs`, replace it with proper usage of `fputc(c, log)` or `fprintf(log, "%c", c)`

You are using fputs which assumes first is a string terminated with a `\0` causing overread and thus an undefined behaviour.

You may get `˜|‚` or something else or may be even segmentation fault depending on factors not known to you.

From man page

> fputc() writes the character c, cast to an unsigned char, to stream.
>   fputs() writes the string s to stream, without its terminating null
>   byte ('\0').

Answer (score 0):

`fputs` expects a NUL terminated *string*.

What you are passing is an address of char which doesn't have any 0 terminator. Your code has *undefined behaviour*. If you want to print char, just use `fputc()`.